# Cannot POST php

Tags: php, html, post, root

I have a really simple php form to learn php. I have the code from a tutorial. My html is:

```
<form action="php/learnphp.php" method="post">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" name="username" size="30" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" name="streetaddress" size="30" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" name="cityaddress" size="30" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

my php file is:

```
<?php

        $usersName = $_POST['username'];
        $streetAddress = $_POST['streetaddress'];
        $cityAddress = $_POST['cityaddress'];

        echo '<p>Your Information</p>';

        // You can combine variables with text using a .

        echo $usersName. ' lives at </br>';
        echo $streetAddress. ' in </br>';
        echo $cityAddress. '</br></br>';       ?>
```

If I press the submit button i get an error that says: Cannot POST /php/learnphp.php.

i have the form in the root map and my php in a map called 'php'. I know it's probably really simple but i cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: learnphp.php and html related files are different ?

Comment: yes there are 2 files:  first is html with form, second is the learnphp.php

Comment: learnphp.php is in folder php ? Can you share both file's location

Comment: are they on the same folder ?

Comment: verify that your action attribute path in your html form is right.

Comment: the rootfolder contains form.html and a folder called 'php'. In the php folder there is a file called learnphp.php

Comment: are you getting 404 error or `Cannot POST`?

Comment: Also can you open directly that php file from url if its opening fine?

Comment: i get a cannot post

Comment: You're posting to localhost, and not to something beginning with `file:///` right?

Answer (score 0):

Could be the path folder is not correct. Try make it like `learnphp.php` same level with `<yourhtmlfile>.html`. Example `root/learnphp.php` and `root/<yourhtmlfile>.html`. And you need to edit your form action

```
<form action="learnphp.php" method="post">
```

Comment: I tried it, but i get the same error. I have changed the form action to "learnphp.php"

Comment: Im not sure this one can help or not but give it a try tho. Adding name to your form and as well as your submit button.

Comment: I tried your code and tested in my local it is working. So weird

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this.It's work for me.

my.php

```
<form action="learnphp.php" method="post">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" name="username" size="30" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" name="streetaddress" size="30" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" name="cityaddress" size="30" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

learnphp.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $usersName = $_POST['username'];
    $streetAddress = $_POST['streetaddress'];
    $cityAddress = $_POST['cityaddress'];

    echo '<p>Your Information</p>';

        // You can combine variables with text using a .

        echo $usersName. ' lives at </br>';
        echo $streetAddress. ' in </br>';
        echo $cityAddress. '</br></br>';     
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking if the submit button is pressed first. If not, print an error message:

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $usersName = $_POST['username'];
        $streetAddress = $_POST['streetaddress'];
        $cityAddress = $_POST['cityaddress'];
    
        echo '<p>Your Information</p>';
    
            // You can combine variables with text using a .
    
            echo $usersName. ' lives at </br>';
            echo $streetAddress. ' in </br>';
            echo $cityAddress. '</br></br>';     


    }else {
      echo "Post Submit is not clicked";
       }
    ?>
```